# Can Jasmine it() take parameters in its function?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

In the following test, I am trying to create output individually for each Tab.  The `it` description works correctly, though I don't know how to pass in the values as the `it` function is run after the for loop has completed.  This is simplified code I would like to pass in more and bigger parameters.

```
describe("condition() on myPage", function () {
    var curTab = 0;
    var page = 13;

    for (var i = curTab; i < 16; ++i) {

        it("Conditionally loop all Third Octave valid props " + i, function (i, page) {
            console.log(i, page);

            expect(myPage[i][page].condition()).toBe(true);
        });
    }

});
```

Is there some other way to iteratively create `it`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I could use the wider scoped variable `curTab` and increment it inside of my `it`.  This way the `curTab` gets updated with the actual run.

```
describe("condition() on myPage", function () {
    var curTab = 0;
    var page = 13;

    for (var i = curTab; i < 16; ++i) {

        it("Conditionally loop all Third Octave valid props " + i, function () {
            console.log(curTab, page);

            expect(myPage[curTab++][page].condition()).toBe(true);
        });
    }
});
```